# How to fix error when downloading pyPDF2 on Python 3.6.0?

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to install the `pyPDF2` package on `Python 3.6.0`. When I open the Command Prompt and type `python -m pip install pyPDF2` I receive the following error:

Successfully built `pyPDF2`
Installing collected packages: `pyPDF2`

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:
>   [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2' Consider using the
>   `--user` option or check the permissions.

Previously, I experienced a similar issue with installing the `pip` library. I had to receive administrative rights from another user before successfully downloading `pip`.

I am using Windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options:

1. Install packages in your user directory using `pip --user` ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57045117/10669875) of PoorProgrammer)

   This is also the solution provided in the error message itself, and should always work.
2. Run the python/pip as administrator ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57044766/10669875) of Sıddık Açıl)

   This is only useful if you have administrative rights.
3. Install Python in a non-protected directory (e.g. `C:\Python\3.6`) instead of in `C:\Program Files`.

   This should work as long as you're allowed to install software on the computer. Once installed, you can install additional packages without administrative rights.
4. Install packages in a virtual environment.

   This also works without administrative rights, but you need to install `virtualenv` once first (e.g. using `python -m pip install --users virtualenv`).

To create a virtual environment for Python 3.6 and install the package in it:

```
py -3.6 -m virtualenv --python=3.6 my_virtual_environent
my_virtual_environent\Scripts\activate
python -m pip install pyPDF2
```

Answer (score 1):

Open `cmd` as an administrator to get elevated access and run your `Python` `pip` install script again.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it locally on your user as well. I assume that you don't want to have to go and get your `cmd` elevated every time so the following should work:

```
python -m pip install --user pyPDF2
```

If you want to see the location, it should be at `%APPDATA%\Python` since you are using windows.